# Having issues with django-allauth

Tags: python, django-models, django-allauth

having issues putting the following into git. "ls ../.pip-modules/lib" and "cp -r ../.pip-modules/lib/python3.12.0/site-packages/allauth/templates/* ./templates"     the code along is using python 3.8 but my version is 3.12.0     im guessing thats the issue?[error message on git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThkC2.png)

I tried inputting "ls ../.pip-modules/lib" and expected to get python version but got error. when I put in python --version instead I got python 3.12.0.
Anyone know what I need to input for
"cp -r ../.pip-modules/lib/python3.12.0/site-packages/allauth/templates/* ./templates"